# Setting the values of an array depending on the values in a separate array [Angular, forEach]

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

I have two sets of arrays, `$scope.Skills` and `$scope.skillslist`.

The `Skills` array has a ton of values, so I'm only including the ones relevant to the question:

```
$scope.Skills = [
    {LotsOfValues: "blah", Skill_Values__c: "1"},
    {LotsOfValues: "blah", Skill_Values__c: "2"},
    {LotsOfValues: "blah", Skill_Values__c: "3"}
];
```

And the `skillslist` array:

```
$scope.skillslist = [
    {Skill_Values__c: "1", Checked: ""},
    {Skill_Values__c: "2", Checked: ""},
    {Skill_Values__c: "3", Checked: ""},
    {Skill_Values__c: "4", Checked: ""},
    {Skill_Values__c: "5", Checked: ""},
    {Skill_Values__c: "6", Checked: ""},
    {Skill_Values__c: "7", Checked: ""}
];
```

What I want to do is, for each item in the `skillslist`, run it against the items in `Skills`, and if there's a match, set Checked to true, if not set it to false. How can this be accomplished?

I'm using the forEach function and this is what I have so far:

```
angular.forEach(skills, function (value) {
    console.log("FOR EACH");
    for (var i = 0; i <= $scope.skillslist.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.skillslist[i].Skill_Values__c === value.Skill_Values__c) {
            $scope.skillslist[i].Checked = "Added";
        } else {
            $scope.skillslist[i].Checked = "no";
        }
    }
});
```

But straight away I know I'm doing it wrong because I should be looking forEach `skillslist` right? But when I do that I have no idea how to then change the Checked value for each one. Swapping all `Skills` for `skillslist` didn't help.

In my ng-repeat of `skillslist`, I see the first item has a Checked value of "Added", the rest have a Checked value of "no".

I've been reading through forEach examples, but couldn't find any related to what I'm trying to do, about referencing two different arrays in this way. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Style suggestions: variable names generally shouldn't be capitalized and don't use sentinel values like "Added" and "no" use the built in boolean values.

Comment: Thanks for that, will keep lowercase in mind next time! I'm only using "added" and "no" as they related to css classes that get applied for the ng-repeat items, I didn't really want class names called true/false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're iterating over `skillslist`, each value passed to your callback will be the individual values of `skillslist`. So if you want to change the values of `skillslist`, you can do so by changing the first argument passed to your callback. Like this:

```
skillslist.forEach(function(skill) {
  var isInSkills = skills.some(function(skillValue) {
    return skillValue.Skill_Values__c === skill.Skill_Values__c;
  });
  if(isInSkills) {
    skill.checked = "Added";
  } else {
    skill.checked = "no";
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that SimpleJ, that's really helpful. I didn't realise I could approach it like that at all for comparing two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at JavaScript's [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
$scope.skillslist.forEach(function (skillFromList) {
    skillFromList.Checked = $scope.Skills.some(function (skill) {
        return skillFromList.Skill_Values__c === skill.Skill_Values__c;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0pm7udeg/)